# C++11 simple regex not working with gcc 4.9.1

Tags: c++, regex, gcc, c++11

I am having problems with simple regex that I wrote:

```
std::regex reg = std::regex("(.*)[a-zA-Z]+(.*)");
```

and it works in a simple program like so :

```
#include <regex>
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::regex reg = std::regex("(.*)[a-zA-Z]+(.*)");

  std::string s("string");
  if(std::regex_match(s, reg)){
    std::cout << "MATCH !" << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

But I have a file that I want to process it with this regex and it doesn't work. File contents:

```
313801.91 323277.59 861.89
313770.97 323272.13 868.89
Start
End
313793.19 323290.19 864.89
```

My program: [full program code](http://pastebin.com/L0qr00kz); [input file](http://pastebin.com/aHKtJPkj)

```
  ...
  std::ifstream input;
  std::string cell;
  std::regex reg = std::regex("(.*)[a-zA-Z]+(.*)");
  input.open("a.txt", std::ofstream::in);
  while (std::getline(input, cell))
  {
    // reject the row if there is any text in it
    if( std::regex_match(cell, reg) ){
      // never hit!
      continue;
    }
  }
  ...
```

When I wanted to print it out I got strange result :

```
cout << "_____\"" << cell << "\"____" << endl;

"____"Start
```

Comment: Are you sure that you can use `std::ofstream::in` in `ifstream`?

Comment: I didn't notice that :( but I have tried `std::ifstream::in` and the same effect.

Comment: @ionagamed Doesn't really matter. That particular enumeration is actually defined in `ios_base`.

Comment: I think that bug is somwhere else in the code or in GCC itself, because it worked fine with Visual Studio 2013 and a breakpoint on `continue`. Try to use GDB with the same breakpoint.

Comment: The code works as expected for me with Clang and libc++.

Comment: Also works as expected on my MinGW GCC 4.9.1.

Comment: Nobody can reproduce, even with gcc. Maybe you should give the exact program (and input) that is failing?

Comment: @MarcGlisse I have just updated the question with full source code and input file.

Comment: Ahhhh... There was a problem with line endings - I had the file with CLRF line endings and I am on Linux now. I have to work around this somehow.

Comment: Why not make the regex simply `[a-zA-Z]` and use `regex_search` instead of `regex_match`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lied in line endings. I had a file saved (probably on Windows) with CLRF line endings.

I updated my regex to this and now it works:

```
std::regex reg("(.*)[a-zA-Z]+(.*)(\r\n|\n|\r)");
```